# Apache FOP and Java Image Issues - Combining multiple sources

Tags: java, xml, apache-fop

I am trying to "automate" the building of a PDF using Apache FOP and Java.  I want to minimize the hard coding since I don't know in advance all the file combinations I am going to need to support.  In addition I want to try and not save files on the hard drive.  Files on the HD introduces security, performance, threading and cleanup considerations I would rather not handle.

The test case I am using right now has 1 FO and 2 PNG files.  One of the PNG files is over 1MB.

Ideally I would create 3 sources:

```
InputStream fo = new InputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\FOP\\Test\\blah.fo"));
InputStream png1 = new InputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\FOP\\Test\\image-1.png"));
InputStream png2 = new InputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\FOP\\Test\\image-2.png"));
Source foSrc = new StreamSource(fo);
Source png1Src = new StreamSource(png1);
Source png2Src = new StreamSource(png2);
```

and then combine them all together to generate the PDF.  I can't find a way using the API to do that.

The FO files refers to the images via:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="file:image-1.png"/>
<fo:external-graphic src="file:image-2.png"/>
```

When I use the command line FOP tools, it builds the PDF as I would expect.  As long as the two images are in the same directory as the FO file, then all is good.  Using the command line, there is no need to point out the existence or location of the images.

When using Java, I have tried a number of configurations, but none of them fit my need:

1. I saved the FO file and the 2 images into the same directory and referred to them using the following FopFactory constructor:

   ```
   private static final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("C:\\Temp\\FOP\\test").toURI());
   ```

   This code base only finds the smaller of the two images.  It seems like the larger one is being ignored since it is bigger than some limit.
2. I have tried the above constructor using various relative and absolute paths.
3. I have tried constructing FopFactory using the default "fop.xconf" file and adding the "C:\Temp\FOP\Test" directory to the classpath.
4. I have "hardcoded" the files and their locations in the FO file.
5. I have tried using intermediate files structure (IFDocumentHandler, IFSerializer and IFConcatenator) for the images and get errors that way.  Seems the intermediate files are not intended for images.
6. I have been able to embed the file into the FO file using base64 encoding and the syntax:

   ```
   <fo:external-graphic src="url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...ggg==')"/>
   ```

The last one seems like the best solution other than taking 3 sources and using all 3 to generate the PDF.  Any suggestions on how to use the API to combine the 3 sources?

Thanks.